# Using lowercase tables with Oracle enhanced and Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, oracle11g

I've got tables in Oracle that have been created with double quotes, in lowercase. Like you would in MySQL.

Oracle enhanced doesn't had double quotes around the name so it fails.

```
DESC people;
```

But this would work instead:

```
DESC "people";
```

How can I force Oracle enhanced to quote the table name without redoing my schema altogether. Here is my model btw.

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

**edit:**

The table name should remain lowercase in this piece of code. In fact `DESC` isn't called even if the error message says so.

https://github.com/rsim/oracle-enhanced/blob/master/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/oracle_enhanced_connection.rb#L30

Comment: The best option ( in the long run ) would be to recreate your schema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only viable solution is to let Oracle handle this and don't force it to use lowercase table names if you want *Ruby OCI8* to be working out of the box.

As Ben said, redoing the schema was the solution here.

Answer (score 1):

I would try doing

```
class Person < ActiveRecord::Base
 set_table_name '"people"'
end
```